# Is it possible that the output of the deep learning shuffled randomly in same batch?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, autoencoder

I'm working with the VAE of 1-dimensional signal : which is kind of noise added sinusoidal signal. To check the shape of the reconstructed output, I draw some graphs with the original signal and VAE reconstructed signal. However, the signals with same index do not seem very resemble but not related signal of index shows the similar shape. I suspect that the output of the deep network is arranged randomly with in the batch range. I used the basic structure from the online examples.

Dataset Load :

```
train_data = signalDataset(train_dataset) 
train_set = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=opt.workers)

for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_set):
    data = data.to(device)
```

Dataset :

```
class signalDataset:

def __init__(self, dataset_name, normalize=True):
    self.dataset_name = dataset_name
    t_data = pd.read_csv(dataset_name, header=None)  
    data = torch.from_numpy(np.expand_dims(np.array([t_data.iloc[i] for i in range(0, len(t_data))]), -1)).float()
    self.data = self.normalize(data) if normalize else data
    self.seq_len = data.size(1)

    # Estimates distribution parameters of deltas (Gaussian) from normalized data
    original_deltas = data[:, -1] - data[:, 0]
    self.original_deltas = original_deltas
    self.or_delta_max, self.or_delta_min = original_deltas.max(), original_deltas.min()
    deltas = self.data[:, -1] - self.data[:, 0]
    self.deltas = deltas
    self.delta_mean, self.delta_std = deltas.mean(), deltas.std()
    self.delta_max, self.delta_min = deltas.max(), deltas.min()

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)

def __getitem__(self, idx):

    return self.data[idx]

def normalize(self, x_list):
    x_norm = torch.empty(0, dtype=torch.float)
    for x in x_list :
        self.max = x.max()
        self.min = x.min()
        # self.max = abs(x).max()
        # self.min = (-1) * abs(x).max()
        # x = (2 * (x - self.min) / (self.max - self.min) - 1) # -1~1
        x = (x - self.min) / (self.max - self.min) # 0~1
        x = torch.unsqueeze(x, 0)
        x_norm = torch.cat([x_norm, x], dim=0)
        # x = torch.sigmoid(x)

    return x_norm

def denormalize(self, x):
    if not hasattr(self, 'max') or not hasattr(self, 'min'):
        raise Exception("You are calling denormalize, but the input was not normalized")
    return 0.5 * (x * self.max - x * self.min + self.max + self.min)

def sample_deltas(self, number):
    return (torch.randn(number, 1) + self.delta_mean) * self.delta_std

def normalize_deltas(self, x):
    return ((self.delta_max - self.delta_min) * (x - self.or_delta_min) / (
            self.or_delta_max - self.or_delta_min) + self.delta_min)
```

LSTM VAE :

```
class LSTM_VAE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,
             input_size=60000,
             hidden=[1024, 512, 256, 128, 64],
             latent_size=1024,
             num_layers=2,
             bidirectional=True):
    super().__init__()

    self.input_size = input_size
    self.hidden = hidden
    self.latent_size = latent_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.bidirectional = bidirectional

    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    self.encode = nn.LSTM(input_size=self.input_size,
                          hidden_size=self.hidden[0],
                          num_layers=2,
                          batch_first=True,
                          bidirectional=True)

    self.decode = nn.LSTM(input_size=self.latent_size,
                          hidden_size=self.hidden[2],
                          num_layers=2,
                          batch_first=True,
                          bidirectional=True)

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[0]*2, self.hidden[1])
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[1], self.hidden[2])
    self.fc31 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[2], self.latent_size)
    self.fc32 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[2], self.latent_size)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
    self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)

    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[2]*2, self.hidden[1])
    self.fc5 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[1], self.hidden[0])
    self.fc6 = nn.Linear(self.hidden[0], self.input_size)

def encoder(self, x):
    x = torch.unsqueeze(x, 1)
    x, _ = self.encode(x)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)

    mu = self.fc31(x)
    log_var = self.fc32(x)

    return mu, log_var

def decoder(self, z):
    z, _ = self.decode(z)
    z = self.fc4(z)
    z = self.fc5(z)
    z = self.fc6(z)
    z = torch.sigmoid(z)

    return torch.squeeze(z)

def sampling(self, mu, log_var):
    std = torch.exp(0.5 * log_var)
    eps = torch.randn_like(std)

    return mu + eps * std

def forward(self, x):
    mu, log_var = self.encoder(x.view(-1, self.input_size))
    z = self.sampling(mu, log_var)
    z = self.decoder(z)

    return z, mu, log_var
```

I searched for batch data disturbing and data arrangement but nothing helpful came up. I wonder is the output shuffle in batch possible? Or just my code have something wrong in it?
Any opinion or suggestion would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Are you using a torch Dataloader? How exactly are you passing the data to the network? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Dear @GoodDeeds  I added data load part!

Comment: You seem to have selected `shuffle=True` in the data loader, so it is shuffling your data. (`train_set = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=opt.workers)`)

Comment: @GoodDeeds I understand the shuffle parameter at dataloader :D What I objected was if there were four signals with index 1 to 4, the output signal also has 1 to 4 index each. As using VAE, input index 1 signal should be identical with output index 1 signal but the results show output index 3 is identical with input index 1. The index is just, example but this kind of results kept show up.